# CS0103 the name 'txtname' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i get 'txtname','txthours','txtrate', and 'textgrosspay' does not exist in the current context. error code  is CS0103. i have matched the words from the text boxes i have on designer with these words as well. any help is appreciated.

This image here shows the design part of my web form: [image: this image here shows the design part of my web form]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Grosspayapp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Compute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name;
        String shours, srate;
        int hours;
        double rate, grosspay;

        name = txtname.Text;

        shours = txthours.Text;
        hours = Convert.ToInt32(shours);

        srate = txtrate.Text;
        rate = Convert.ToDouble(srate);

        grosspay = hours * rate;

        txtgrosspay.Text = grosspay.ToString();

    }

}
```

the source code is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Grosspayapp.aspx.cs" Inherits="GrossPayApp3_20.GrossPayProgram" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            font-size: xx-large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <span class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Gross Pay Application </span>
            <br />
        </div>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            Hours&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txthours" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            Rate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdcompute" runat="server" OnClick="Compute_Click" Text="Compute Gross Pay" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Gross Pay&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtgrosspay" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show the source for your `.aspx`, not just the screenshot of the designer.

Comment: Just added the source code as well thank you.

Comment: Where's the `<% @Page %>` directive?

Comment: sorry about that I spaced it out and it now shows the directive.

Comment: do you have a file "Grosspayapp.designer.cs" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `Inherits` of the `<%@ Page` directive should reference the page's class name `Grosspayapp`, but you have

```
Inherits="GrossPayApp3_20.GrossPayProgram"
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed my errors and now my program is running.